# Simplifying a Double Random procedure

Tags: puzzle, random

Thought this would be a nice puzzle for some. :)

First, I take a random number from 1 to 10, then take that number and multiply it by 5, we'll call this result 'threshold'.
Then I take another new random number from 1 to 100, and see if it is equal or lower than the 'threshold' number.

pseudocode:

```
th = rand(10) * 5;
res = rand(100);
if (res <= th) return TRUE;
```

Is this the simplest way to calculate this?
I'm thinking one of rand(500) or rand(1000) would be the same, but I can't get my probability formulas to work.

Comment: Why would you do something like this? On that note: the straightforward approach does what you want, so why do you expect something simpler?

Comment: Equivalent would be "if (rand(1000) <= 275) return TRUE;" as the probability of your program returning TRUE is 27.5%.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already given the answer, but I thought it might be useful to show in some detail how to arrive at it:

Let $X \in \{1,\dotsc,10\}$ be the first random variable, and let $Y \in \{1,\dotsc,100\}$ be the second.  The probability that $Y \le 5X$, *given* that $X$ has the value $x$, is

$$\mathrm P(Y \le 5X \;|\; X=x) = \mathrm P(Y \le 5x) = \frac{5x}{100}.$$

$X$ takes all values with equal probability, so, for any given $x \in \{1,\dotsc,10\}$, $\mathrm P(X=x) = \frac{1}{10}$.  Therefore, the probability that $X=x$ *and* $Y \le 5X$ is

$$\mathrm P(Y \le 5X \text{ and } X=x) = \mathrm P(Y \le 5X \;|\; X=x)\; \mathrm P(X=x) = \frac{5x}{100} \frac{1}{10} = \frac{5x}{1000}.$$

To get the marginal probability that $Y \le 5X$, we then simply need to sum over all possible values of $X$:

$$\mathrm P(Y \le 5X) = \sum_{x=1}^{10}\; \mathrm P(Y \le 5X \text{ and } X=x) = \sum_{x=1}^{10}\frac{5x}{1000}.$$

The final step is either remembering the formula for the [sum of an arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) or just working it out by hand:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{10}\frac{5x}{1000} = \frac{5}{1000} \sum_{x=1}^{10}\; x = \frac{5}{1000} (1 + \cdots + 10) = \frac{5}{1000} 55 = \frac{275}{1000} = \frac{11}{40}.$$

Thus, the probability that your pseudocode returns true is $\frac{275}{1000} = \frac{11}{40}$, and so it can be replaced by

```
if (rand(1000) <= 275) return TRUE;
```

or even by

```
if (rand(40) <= 11) return TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The possibility of res being less than or equal to th is th / 100. If you add 5, 6, 7,... 50, or all the possibilities of th, you get 1265. Divide that by the number of possible values of th (46), and you get 27.5/100 as the probability that res <= th. Or take (5+50) / 2 / 100.

Comment: The way the problem is stated, there are only ten possible values of *th*: 5, 10, 15, ..., 50. The errors in your calculation fortuitously cancel out!

Comment: Oops! You're right.